# How can I get green color rectangle if result is True and Red box if result is False in result = (paper == dict_k)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to add id text and rectangle with green if result is True and Red if result is false. I am able to get the id in text from live data but I don't get the rectangle with color. Can someone please help me with this issue. When I remove the rectangle block I am able to get id and True/False result

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  # constructor
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    # counter
    # self.i = 0
    # add QLabel
    self.top = 150
    self.left = 150
    self.width = 1000
    self.height = 1000
    self.qLbl = QLabel('Not yet initialized')
    self.setCentralWidget(self.qLbl)
    # make QTimer
    self.qTimer = QTimer()
    # set interval to 1 s
    self.qTimer.setInterval(1000) # 1000 ms = 1 s
    # connect timeout signal to signal handler
    # label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 20))
    self.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font: 16pt Arial}")
    self.qTimer.timeout.connect(self.getSensorValue)
    self.qTimer.timeout.connect(self.paintevent)

    # start timer
    self.qTimer.start()


  def getSensorValue(self):
    # self.i += 1
    # print('%d. call of getSensorValue()' % self.i)
    id = 'ID1123'
    t = neo4jconnection(paper_id=id)
    paper = neo4jresultparser(t)
    dict_k = jsonfilereader(paper_id=id)  # probably not need it
    result = (paper == dict_k)
    self.qLbl.setText((id +" "+str( result)))

def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QPainter(self)
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.green, Qt.SolidPattern))
    painter.drawRect(40, 40, 400, 200)


qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
# setup GUI
qWin = MainWindow()
qWin.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 1000)
qWin.show()
# run application
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call paintEvent directly but through the update() or repaint() methods, on the other hand the color must be an attribute of the class that changes according to the value of result and then call update():

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font: 16pt Arial}")
        self.qLbl = QLabel("Not yet initialized")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.qLbl)

        self.qTimer = QTimer()
        self.qTimer.setInterval(1000)
        self.qTimer.timeout.connect(self.getSensorValue)
        self.qTimer.start()

        self.color = QColor()

    def getSensorValue(self):
        id_ = "ID1123"
        t = neo4jconnection(paper_id=id_)
        paper = neo4jresultparser(t)
        dict_k = jsonfilereader(paper_id=id_)
        result = paper == dict_k
        self.qLbl.setText("{} {}".format(id_, result))
        self.color = QColor("green") if result else QColor("red")
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.color.isValid():
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.color, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(self.color, Qt.SolidPattern))
            painter.drawRect(40, 40, 400, 200)
```